# X-Powered-By header set by Azure Traffic Manager

Tags: azure, iis-8.5, azure-traffic-manager

I am having trouble removing the `X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5` header which is being set by the **Azure Traffic Manager**.

I have the following architecture:

Web VM (IIS/8.5) `->` Routing VM (ARR/2.5 IIS/8.5) `->` Azure Traffic Manager `->` Custom Domain Name.

- When I make a HTTP request to my Web VM there are no `X-Powered-By`
  headers
- When I make a HTTP request to my Routing VM there are no
  `X-Powered-By` headers
- When I make a HTTP request to my traffic manager, i.e. http://my_app.trafficmanager.net then the `X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5` **header appears**.

Is this a known issue within Azure Traffic Manager?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Traffic Manager works at the DNS level.  It uses dynamically-generated DNS responses to direct end users to the appropriate service endpoint, chosen based on the DNS query, configured traffic routing method, and current endpoint health status.

Once DNS resolution is complete, the end user/client connects to the service endpoint *directly*, not through Traffic Manager.  HTTP/S traffic flows directly between client and service, and not through Traffic Manager.

Thus Traffic Manager never sees, and cannot in any way influence, your HTTP headers.